# Node JS and Socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to write an object with member functions for receiving and sending data to and from the client with Node JS and Socket IO.  The problem is that every time I send data from the client, there is a new 'connection' event that fires.  Is that how it works?  I thought the connection event would only occur on a new connection.  So with the code below, the log echoes 'New connection' with every reception from the client.  It doesn't seem right.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

console.log('New connection');

var localSocket = socket;

var newsock = new UserSocket(localSocket);

newsock.game = null;
newsock.host = null;
newsock.opponent = null;
newsock.room = "";

newsock.SendToHostSocket('Welcome to Baseball Strategy II');

arrSockets.push(socket);

});


function UserSocket(sock) {

var localSock = sock;

var o = this;

this.sock = localSock;

this.sock.on('clientData', function (data) {

    console.log("user socket object");
    console.log(o);
    o.ParseClientData(data);

});

}
```

This is a simplified version of what I have for the client:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

var socket = io.connect('http://local.baseball.com:3333');

function SocketGameOut(outstring) {

    socket.emit('clientData', outstring );

}


$("#hostGame").click( function () {

    var gamenum = $('input[name=gameSelect]:checked', '#gameForm').val();

    var aSendData = { command : "newgame" , senddata : { gameid : gamenum } };
    var senddata = JSON.stringify(aSendData);
    SocketGameOut(senddata);

});


});
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show how you are sending data from the client? You understanding is correct; `connection` should only be fired once per connection, not once per message. (Also, do a quick sanity check and make sure you're not accidentally logging `"New connection"` elsewhere in your code.)

Comment: There could be an error during transport.  This typically resets the connection.

Comment: That happens every time?

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but it looks fine. I am nearly certain this is a problem with your server/network configuration. Can you test it running everything on `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below it worked for me.

```
//use once.('connection') instead of on.('connection')


io.sockets.once('connection', function (socket) {

console.log('New connection');

var localSocket = socket;

var newsock = new UserSocket(localSocket);

newsock.game = null;
newsock.host = null;
newsock.opponent = null;
newsock.room = "";

newsock.SendToHostSocket('Welcome to Baseball Strategy II');

arrSockets.push(socket);
```

});